# How many times can I upgrade my lightning spell?

Tags: clash-of-clans

Ok so I have the game Clash of Clans. My Research Laboratory is level 3. How many times can I upgrade my lightning spell before it asks me to upgrade my research to level 4?

Answer (score 2):

At Lab level 3, the maximum level you can research for Lightning is 4.

Overall, the maximum level for the Lightning spell (currently, at least) is 6:

http://clashofclans.wikia.com/wiki/Lightning_Spell

Though you'll need the eighth level lab (requires Town Hall 10) to get that far.

Answer (score 2):

The maximum level you can obtain in Research Lab Level 3 is level 4(for your lightning spell).  If you want your Lightning spell to be leveled up to level 5, you must upgrade your Research Lab to level 4.

As BiscuitBaker stated, the highest level you can get on Lightning spell is level 6(at least for right now).

[Source](http://clashofclans.wikia.com/wiki/Lightning_Spell)

Answer (score 0):

Well, indeed it used to be 6 but the answers provided are outdated. Since after that there are various updates, so, now the Max lv is 7.

Comment: Except that wasn't the question...